# Is there any difference between django.conf.settings and import settings?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

What is the basic difference between the following import statements in a Django app?

```
import settings
```

and

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Comment: +1 because it is a very interesting questions for who is new to Django development.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
import settings
```

Will import settings(.py) module of your Django project (if you are writing this code from the "root" package of your application, of course)

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Will import settings **object** from django.conf package (Django's provided files). [This is important](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code), because

> [..] note that your code should not import from either global_settings or your own settings file. django.conf.settings abstracts the concepts of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single interface. It also decouples the code that uses settings from the location of your settings.

UPDATE: if you want to define some own settings, see [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings)

Comment: FYI, global_settings is another module inside django.conf package. As the documentation says, do not use it.

Comment: Note that using ```from django.conf import settings``` is critical if you want to be able to overwrite settings during unit testing as well.

Comment: Also note that all settings names **should be upper-case**. That is, if your have a var `my_var` in your settings then this will fail: `from django.conf import settings`... `settings.my_var`. But if you name it `MY_VAR` it will succeed!