# Proper way to import a single Django settings constant to avoid the full settings import overhead?

Tags: python, django, import

From [Django - Difference between import django.conf.settings and import settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780756/django-importing-settings-file), I understand the accepted way to import the settings file:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

I've also read [Good or bad practice in Python: import in the middle of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188640/good-or-bad-practice-in-python-import-in-the-middle-of-a-file).  One of the answers there takes you to http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-July/699176.html, where points #2 and #4 are relevant to my question.

Let's say I have a huge settings.py and throughout my Django code, I only need to use a "lowly" constant like MEDIA_ROOT in one rarely-called method.  So, it seems incredibly wasteful to import the entire settings.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
def foo():
    my_media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

when I can just import the one needed constant:

```
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT
...
def foo():
    my_media_root = MEDIA_ROOT
```

and therefore avoid importing the huge settings.py, especially since it may never even be used, if my_media_root is used in only one out of many methods in that file.  Of course, this is bad practice, but the "good practice version" of this doesn't work:

```
from django.conf.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
...
def foo():
    my_media_root = MEDIA_ROOT
```

as, by design, it causes the expected `ImportError: No module named settings` exception.

So, my question is, what is the proper way to import just one constant from a large settings.py?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is a Django project, then the settings file has already been imported, it doesn't cost you anything to simply import it and use the constant you want.  Importing a module many times in Python only executes the file once.

The usual way to import settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

This just assigns one name in your module (`settings`) to the value of an existing already-imported settings object.  It's equivalent to, and has about the same execution time as:

```
settings = sys.modules['django.conf'].settings
```

Have you found problems doing it the simple way?

Comment: Yes. Massively premature optimisation otherwise.