# static url path setting in django

Tags: python, css, django, django-cms

I am new to django, presently I am learning and trying to build a basic site with django-cms. Below are my project folder structure and code files

```
project_folder
    manage.py 
    main_folder 
         static
             css
                new-styles.css
             js
                new-styles.js
         templates                      
             base.html
             home.html
         media
             pic_1.gif 
             .....
         settings.py
         urls.py
         .......
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'templates'))
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
       'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
       'django.core.context_processors.request',
       'django.core.context_processors.media',
       'django.core.context_processors.static',
       'django.core.context_processors.debug',
       'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
       'cms.context_processors.media',
       'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)
......
.......
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
            url(r'^$', ...........),               
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns
```

**base.html**

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{%block "title" %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/new-styles.css">
  {% render_block "css" %}
  </head> 
  <body>
  {% cms_toolbar %}
    {% block "base_content" %}
    {% endblock %}
  {% render_block "js" %}  
  </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% block "title" %}Welcome to Services{% endblock %}
{% block "base_content" %}
  <p>Hi this is paragraph</p>
  <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/promo3.jpg" />
 {% placeholder "number_one" %} 
 {% endblock %}
```

**new-styles.css**

```
body {  
    padding:0px; margin:0px; margin-top:40px;
        background-color:#b0c4de;
     }
p {
      background-color:#e0ffff;
  }
```

So above are my complete project structure and code files, but my actual problem is `new-styles.css` file is not working, even though I had written some css code in the file it is not linking to the template, so can anyone please let me know whats wrong and why `base.html` template file is unable to access the `new-styles.css` file, whether the path given in `link` tag is wrong or the path setting in the `settings.py` is wrong?

Comment: Consider this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles

and this one 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-in-templates

Also modify your urlpatterns:

`
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
`

Comment: yeah i had gone through every link and written code according to the tutorial, i had mentioned entire code above  because i am unable to find why template can't render/use the css file ?

Comment: Did you add `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py?

Take a look here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor

Comment: yeah i had used it and edited settings.py file code above

Comment: Did you put files to static folder by yourself or do it with `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: oh actually i created myself a folder called static,i created again two folders css which consists of new-services.css and js which consists of new-services.js. After that i had run python manage.py collectstatic by which all the files are grouped int o my static folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23957/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-denis-nikanorov)

Comment: Hi if u don't mind can we continue this in chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23957/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-denis-nikanorov

Answer (score 5):

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from project_name import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .....................
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: You've used both `static` and `staticfiles_urlpatterns`. Can you elaborate on why and the differences between them?

Comment: You should not import settings directly like that, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780907/13824776). Instead use:
```from django.conf import settings```