# What's the difference between `from django.conf import settings` and `import settings` in a Django project

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm reading up that most people do `from django.conf import settings` but I don't undertstand the difference to simply doing `import settings` in a django project file. Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: django.conf settings are django default or "global" settings which you may override with your own project based settings.

Comment: NEVER EVER use the second form. The first one is the only correct one.

Comment: But why never use the second one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Importing Settings File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780756/django-importing-settings-file)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`import settings` will import the first python module named `settings.py` found in `sys.path`. Usually (in default django setups) it allows access only to your site defined settings file, which overwrites django default settings (`django.conf.global_settings`).

So, if you try to access a valid django setting not specified in your settings file you will get an error.

`django.conf.settings` is not a file but an object (see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5659015/django/conf/__init__.py#L308)) making an abstraction of the concepts, default settings and your site-specific settings. Django also does other checks when you use `from django.conf import settings`.

You can also find it in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code).

Comment: `import settings` will import the first python module named `settings.py` found in `sys.path`. This may not be the "site defined settings file", which is looked up in the environment variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" and can be just any python package or module.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks you. I update my answer taking aware of your correction.

Comment: Keeping `settings.py` next to `manage.py` (in the project root) is a default Django setup? O.o I believe the default one is to have it at `<project-name>/settings.py`. At least that's where `django-admin startproject` puts it.

Answer (score 37):

`from django.conf import settings` is better option.

I use different settings files for the same django project (one for "live", one for "dev"), the first one will select the one being executed.