# Importing settings in Django

Tags: python, django

I was looking at the [Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf) on GitHub (specifically the django.conf module) and I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780756/django-importing-settings-file) that you should never import the global_settings module itself, but rather just:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

So I know this works and all that, but as someone who is getting used to looking at the source code to understand how the some of the "under the hood" stuff works for Django, I'd like to get more detail on how I can import "settings" when there is no settings.py in the django/conf directory.

I'm assuming that this is a django built-in where you "from django.conf import settings" and it's intercepted by the django engine and the correct settings module is built/etc. then passed along. Is this the case, or is there something else happening here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

`from django.conf import settings` says "look for the `django.conf` module and import a variable called `settings` from it".

`django.conf` is a package, so the source code `django.conf` *module* can be found in the file [`django/conf/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py). Looking at that, there is a variable at the end called `settings` which is an instance of `LazySettings`. The source code for `LazySettings` can be found near the beginning of the file.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought it was a django question, but even better it turned out to be a python question. Thanks so much! (and I'll add a python tag, well just because)

Comment: We can print `settings.BASE_DIR` in Python shell. But where is `BASE_DIR` defined in `LazySettings` class ?